# jquerymobile Navibar selector breaking

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my application i am using navibar to display bottom tab menu evering thing working fine but  when i am selecting highlighter is braking[image] 
as shown above image. bellow code i am using.

```
<!-------------Footer---------------------------------------->

<div data-role="footer" class="test1"  id="bottom-footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar" class="test1" data-grid="d">
       <ul data-transition="none"> 
        <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_walloffame" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top" > Wall</a></li>
        <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_associateview" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top">Associate</a></li>
        <li><a data-transition="none" name="menu_nav_managersview" id="menu_nav_managersview" data-icon="custom" >Managers</a></li>
        <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_treasurechest" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top" >Treasure</a></li>
        <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_redeem" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top" >Redeem</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!---------footer----------------->
```

Comment: I tried your codes, and working fine for me.
Did you make any changes to css class ".ui-btn-active" in main css file?

Comment: no i didn't use this in my css.what is use of this .ui-btn-active

Comment: css that will change your active blue color on click. it is in jquery mobile default css.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/zVgAz/

Or try this jquery..( it also works although without this script )

## JQUERY

```
$('ul#footer_nav').on('vclick', 'li', function() {
    $( "ul#footer_nav" ).navbar({
        create: function( event, ui ) {}
    }); 
});
```

## HTML

```
<div data-role="footer" class="test1"  id="bottom-footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="test1" data-grid="d">
           <ul id="footer_nav" data-transition="none"> 
            <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_walloffame" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top" > Wall</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_associateview" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top">Associate</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="none" name="menu_nav_managersview" id="menu_nav_managersview" data-icon="custom" >Managers</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_treasurechest" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top" >Treasure</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_redeem" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top" >Redeem</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
```